# Mapping arc or circle as straight line

Tags: coordinate-system, circle

I'm trying to find information about the possibilities to map an arc (or a circle to be specific) as a straight line. Imagine a circle mapped onto a country or continent, that represents a path with a starting point 'A'. The circle has a small buffer. I'm trying to map this path into a straight line starting and ending with point 'A', so that I end up with, instead of a square map containing the circle, a very long (length of the path) and thin (height of the buffer) rectangle shaped map.

I figure that I will need to create a custom projection of some sort, and possibly splitting the circle into two or more arcs. But I have a hard time finding a grip on the subject, and think I might be overlooking a simple solution.

Comment: Two-point equidistant projection ends up with a straight line between the two defining point. Otherwise, I'm having trouble picturing your "circle". Is it literally a circle or two paths between points A and B?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, two-point equidistant would work if the path was actually straight. However, the path is actually a circle, say, for example, the [Large Hadron Collider at CERN](http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/rcid/images/image/LHC_map.jpg). What I'm trying to do is map the Large Hadron Collider from Point 1 to Point 8 as if it's a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indirect way would be to project the data into an azimuthal projection, centered at your location.

Change its projected coordinate reference system by redefining/modifying it so the center is at a pole. Unproject to lat/lon or reproject to a cylindrical projection (not web Mercator).